# angularjs form custom validation derective

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I try to make all fields to be error after first field is changed. But i cant get what is wrong, why second field never turns by error.

here is simple sample [page on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDX1QZMGNZCI)
and code
front part:

```
<form name="mainform" id="mainform">
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
      <label>first</label>
      <input name="capital" ng-model="capital" validatecapitalparts>
    </md-input-container>

    <div layout-gt-sm="row">
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
      <label>second</label>
      <input name="onecost" ng-model="onecost">
    </md-input-container>

</form> 

<h1>{{mainform.capital.$valid}}</h1>
<h1>{{mainform.onecost.$valid}}</h1>
```

Controllers part:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('validatecapitalparts', function() {

      return {

        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('onecost', false);
                ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('capital', false);
                return viewValue;
            });

            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
                ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('onecost', false);
                ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('capital', false);
                return modelValue;
            });


        } 
      };
    });
```

Comment: Your title says angular 2, but this is obviously angularJS.... Is that a typo (title I mean)?

Comment: main idea is to make one field to be error after other field is changed in angular 2, but for example i chosed easiest way to put it on W3. i am realy new in angular, if i make mistakes please say it to me. thanks.

Comment: Yes, well your code is not angular 2 at all, it is AngularJS. So which do you want to do, Angular (2) or AngularJS? :) Just wondering, if you want to do AngularJS, change your title and remove the Angular2 tag from your question so that there won't be confusion :)